# Nest snow thermostat with a McLain PEG-45 boiler

Tags: thermostat, nest

I have a problem similar to the one in [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136840/where-to-connect-my-c-wire-on-the-boiler-side-weil-mclain-gas-boiler). My R wire from the thermostat to the G terminal on boiler and the W wire from the thermostat to the Y terminal on the boiler. The picture is a bit confusing since the red and white from thermostat were connected to 2 black wires.

Comment: Similar to what? If it's another question here, please do include a link to it. Pictures of _your_ wiring (thermostat and boiler wiring blocks) are always helpful, just [edit] them right in to your question.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136840/where-to-connect-my-c-wire-on-the-boiler-side-weil-mclain-gas-boiler

This is the link to ordinal ask.

Comment: https://share.icloud.com/photos/0fwSF4A-5erIIDyiwEEfNstSQ#Union_-_Livingston

Comment: https://share.icloud.com/photos/0TB446ajm2YcaMIs3ZpdJSxJQ#Union_-_Livingston

Comment: https://share.icloud.com/photos/0aov94TVY2_OHsJAH9J13gD6A#Union_-_Livingston

Comment: https://share.icloud.com/photos/0GJfeSIj_eyXeug8dVE0DfmTQ#Union_-_Livingston

Comment: https://share.icloud.com/photos/0x7ZuKbmU7A9AfEF7rTkwOVCA#Union_-_Livingston

Comment: Is your boiler set up to produce hot water or steam? I ask because the [control supplement](https://www.weil-mclain.com/sites/default/files/field-file/eg-standing-pilot-control-supplement_1.pdf) for the EG/PEG Series 4 boilers only discusses the use of the PEG boilers for steam....

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @FrankWeber, Stack Exchange sites are not like a forum where you just tag more posts on to the end. You need to *edit your question* to add additional information (like your pictures), better describe your situation, and *actually ask a question*.

Comment: The boiler is steam heating radiators. I also noticed I have a third wire that was not connected to either the thermostat or boiler. Can I connect that to the C port on both thermostat and boiler. Will that work? Thanks

Comment: @FrankWeber -- what are you trying to accomplish with using the Nest to control a steam system? Also, do you have a pressuretrol or vaporstat on your boiler, and do you have one pipe or two pipes connected to your radiators?

Comment: Not sure about the pressuretrol  or vapor stat. There is only one pipe going to my radiators

Answer (score 0):

### You'll need to run a 4 wire thermostat cable

The issue with your proposals so far is that unlike many setups, your boiler (and some other Weil-McLain boilers as well) puts various safety controls *ahead* of the intended thermostat connection point in a steam configuration (see page 8 of the [control supplement](https://www.weil-mclain.com/sites/default/files/field-file/eg-standing-pilot-control-supplement_1.pdf)), so the wire that's typically connected to R isn't actually constant power.  To avoid thermostat derangement in the case of a safety cutout or worse yet, bypassing a critical safety control (such as your all-important low-water cutoff!!!), you'll need to pull a 4-wire cable instead of your existing 3-wire cable, then wire it as follows:

- Nest Rc to boiler R
- Nest C to boiler C
- Nest Rh to boiler G
- and Nest W to boiler Y