# Nest c-wire question about Honeywell c8610u

Tags: wiring, thermostat, heating

[Where to connect my “c” wire on the boiler side. Weil mclain gas boiler](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/136840/where-to-connect-my-c-wire-on-the-boiler-side-weil-mclain-gas-boiler/136937#136937)

I have this boiler rebuild adapter. Can I connect the c-wire to that somewhere or would it have to connect to the Weil-Mcclain transformer? I have a heat only system. The nest currently has 2 wires Rh and W.

[image: Honeywell s8610u]

Comment: Not an expert, but I think the 24V GND is the ground for your theromostat.